# JSON conversion failing from js string to string[] .net

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, json

model:-

```
public class CreatePostBindingModel
{
    public string[] Text { get; set; }
}
```

the error I am getting is:-

```
"model.Text":["Error converting value \"sdgwegwehwehw\" to type 'System.String[]'.
```

**EDIT:** adding my angular frontend, I dont see the json here, just RequestOptions, am I missing something? :-

```
updateStatus(objPostSetting: PostModel) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "bearer " + LoggedInUser.getLoggedInUser().Token.access_token);
    let opts = new RequestOptions();
    opts.headers = headers;


    return this.objHttp.post(webService("/Post/CreatePost"), objPostSetting, opts)
      .map((res: Response) => {

            return res.json();
          }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Please include your `Json` on question as well.

Comment: Cause `sdgwegwehwehw` is essentially a string literal and not a array of string

Comment: Please put your json and the code where you convert it.

Comment: Also, what serializer are you using?  [tag:json.net]?  [tag:system.text.json]?  A [mcve] with that completely demonstrates the problem with code and JSON would be awesome.

Comment: I am not well aware of the structure of this application, some other developer was working on it previously. I just started on it today